# How can i lock mac every x minutes?

Tags: time, blocking, lock

Is there a simple way / app to say for example: every 30 minutes lock computer for 5 minutes (and don't let any easy way to cancel while this 5 minutes break is happening)?

I know you can set a daily use time, and i know you can schedule locking time. but those are not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

*This ought to be in a comment. No enough reps*

Please clarify:
a. You want to enforce locking after 30 minutes of Desktop session?

***Answered Here*** https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445525. Automator.app is the tool of choice. use the command:

```
sudo shutdown -s +30
```

b. Gently remind the user to lock screen after 30 minutes and take a break?

*for b. these are the possibilities:* Setup a reminder with a Timer app. 
Use Key chain access/ Hot Corners/ or Add an icon to the dock.

Comment: I edited my question because i forgot to mention i need it to stay lock for 5 minutes or so, but for your question it's more similar to the option a you mentioned.

Comment: Stay locked for 5 minutes and then resume again?

Automatically unlocking a locked session beats the purpose it was designed for - security, that is.

Comment: Didn't really understand you. first of all the purpost is not secuirity at all. second, it can be resumed to the login screen state so you need the password.

Answer (score 0):

> One way to do this is to set a `cron` job that activates the ScreenSaver App which ends up 
>   locking your screen.

---

Reproducing the relevant snippet from [this repo on Github](https://github.com/amar-sharma/sleep-on-time)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Written by Amar Sharma <amarsharma.hacker@gmail.com>

lock_screen() {
  sudo open -a /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app || true
}
```

---

<sub>A friend of mine made this script that come night time will change your password and lock your mac every `X` minutes and email you the password to make it cumbersome to continue using your mac every day.</sub>


<sub>[Link to Source Code on Github](https://github.com/amar-sharma/sleep-on-time)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for a more simple solution (no coding :), but any way how can i use this code to repeat this every 30 minutes?

Comment: Also i edited my question because i forgot to mention i need it to stay lock for 5 minutes or so.

Comment: I see, what if, this same script had the following behavior:
1. Lock and change password to random string every 30 minutes
2. Change password back to old password after 5 minutes

Comment: That could be fine... i guess. how would you do it?